# How to kill process after my android app exit?

Tags: android, android-activity

After I pressed back key to exit my android app, the process of this app still exists:

```
$ adb shell ps |grep -is accelerometerplay
u0_a122   2679  139   504048 23968 ffffffff 400d13c4 S com.example.android.accelerometerplay
```

I add some code in onDestroy():

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

Is this enough?
Or I have to do some extra things?

Comment: I think KillProcess would kill only the particular process ID. If process are in stack, all will not be destroyed!

Comment: Use `onStop()`.  `onDestroy()` is only guaranteed to be called if you `finish()` your activity.  It is not even guaranteed if your app goes to the background and is killed.  Read about the activity life cycle.  You can see this by putting a breakpoint on `super.onDestroy()`, it will not hit the breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

                return false;
            }

            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

Comment: This is OK, but what if the activity is killed for reasons other than back key?

Comment: cause your app still running in background and haven't called onDestroy().... Along with this code try to override onKeyDown as given answer by Vishal .. should work properly

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? Android takes care of it itself, when he will not have enough resources.